# Icon className doesn't update on state change

Tags: reactjs, themes, toggle, classname

I am trying simplest ever theme toggle in react with context and don't seem to be able to get the icon re-render when context changes. Everything else works just fine: colors, background image... It renders either of icons depending on initial state, but icon doesn't update when theme is toggled.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { ThemeContext } from "../../contexts/ThemeContext"

const ThemeToggle = () => {
  const { isDarkMode, dark, light, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)
  const theme = isDarkMode ? dark : light
  return (
    <li
      style={{ background: theme.bgPrimary, color: theme.text }}
      onClick={toggleTheme}
    >
      <i className={theme.ico} />
    </li>
  )
}

export default ThemeToggle
```

Context:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react"

export const ThemeContext = createContext()

class ThemeContexProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isDarkMode: false,
    light: {
      text: "#333",
      bgPrimary: "#eee",
      bgSecondary: "#333",
      ico: "fas fa-moon"
    },
    dark: {
      text: "#ddd",
      bgPrimary: "#000003",
      bgSecondary: "#bbb",
      ico: "fas fa-sun"
    }
  }
  toggleTheme = () => {
    this.setState({ isDarkMode: !this.state.isDarkMode })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider
        value={{ ...this.state, toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default ThemeContexProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this installing dedicated react fa package, still don't know why above doesn't work. This works though:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faMoon } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { faSun } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
//.....
  return (
    <li
      style={{ background: theme.bgPrimary, color: theme.text }}
      onClick={toggleTheme}
    >
      {isDarkMode ? (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSun} />
      ) : (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMoon} />
      )}
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the spaces in your `ico` property could be the issue. Normally this isn't an issue for state/props. Context is possibly to blame for this. This might fix it:

```
<i className={`fas ${theme.ico}`} />
```

Replace your context `ico` properties with just the class that changes `fa-moon` and `fa-sun`

Answer (score 0):

You could have used `key` props in the icon tag. Keys help React identify which items have changed. So it can rerender your icon.

```
{isDarkMode ? (
  <i key={1} icon={faSun} />
) : (
  <i key={2} icon={faMoon} />
)}
```